# Why does the program exit, without waiting for the user input?

Tags: c, memory-management, crash, scanf

This C program is supposed to allocate memory based on number of elements entered by user and add them and print the result. It again prompts if user wants to add more numbers or not. But while entering Y/N the console closes and the program ends unexpectedly. How to solve this ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    int n,i;
    int *ptr,*old_ptr;
    int sum = 0;
    char a;

    printf("Enter the number of elements to be added: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    ptr = calloc(n,sizeof(int));
    ptr = old_ptr;

    printf("Enter the elements:\n");

    for(i = 0;i < n;i++){
        scanf("%d",ptr);
        sum = sum + *ptr;
        ptr++;
    }
    printf("The sum total of the numbers is: %d\n\n\n",sum);

    printf("Do you want to enter more numbers ?\nPress Y/N: ");
    scanf("%c",&a);
    if(a == 'Y'){
        printf("\n\nYou have entered: %c\n\n",a);
        ptr = realloc(old_ptr,sizeof(int)*n);

        printf("Enter the elements:\n");

    for(i = 0;i < n;i++){
        scanf("%d",&ptr);
        sum = sum + *ptr;
        ptr++;
    }
    printf("The total of the numbers is: %d\n\n\n",sum);
    }
    if(a == 'N'){
        printf("Program finished!");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What does this ptr = calloc(n,sizeof(int));
    ptr = old_ptr; mean?!

Comment: Maybe you meant to do `old_ptr = ptr;`? But there is no need for allocating the arrays at all. You can just read into the same `int` variable every time and add it to `sum` as you don't really use the array anyway.

Comment: I believe (not an expert) you need to use the scanf format string `" %s"` (note the space) so it will ignore white space and line breaks.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Thanks for responding. I allocated to the pointer some memory and then on the second try after the prompt and after getting input from user I reallocated memory.

Comment: @kaylum Thanks for responding.No that isn't working either.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie Thanks for responding. I think this is not the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see the modified code.

```
scanf("%c",&a);
```

Problem: `scanf` reads `\n` (ASCII:10) from the input buffer, and does not wait further for user input. The value stored in `a` will be 10 (`\n`). Since `a` is not equal to "Y' or 'N', program exits.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    int n,i;
    int *ptr,*old_ptr;
    int sum = 0;
    char a;

    printf("Enter the number of elements to be added: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    ptr = calloc(n,sizeof(int));
    old_ptr=ptr;

    printf("Enter the elements:\n");

    for(i = 0;i < n;i++){
        scanf("%d",ptr);
        sum = sum + *ptr;
        ptr++;
    }
    printf("The sum total of the numbers is: %d\n",sum);

    printf("Do you want to enter more numbers ?Press Y/N: \n");
    getchar();
    scanf("%c",&a);
    if(a == 'Y'){
        printf("You have entered: %c\n\n",a);
        ptr = realloc(old_ptr,sizeof(int)*n);

        printf("Enter the elements:\n");

    for(i = 0;i < n;i++){
        scanf("%d",ptr);
        sum = sum + *ptr;
        ptr++;
    }
    printf("The total of the numbers is: %d\n\n\n",sum);
    }
    if(a == 'N'){
        printf("Program finished!");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Changes required are:

1. Change `ptr = old_ptr` to `old_ptr=ptr`.
   Reason: Assignment operator's associativity is right to left.
2. Change `scanf("%d",&ptr)` to `scanf("%d",ptr)`
   Reason: `ptr` holds the required address. No need of `&`.
3. Put the `getchar` function to read the extra `\n`
4. Remove the extra `\n` in the `printf` statements.

After these modifications, it worked. Please see the image.[image]

Comment: Thanks for responding. Yeah your edit solves the matter to much extent. But there are still 2 things to take care : 1) [solved] I have to put the second part of the code in a do-while loop to continue adding on. 2) [unsolved] How to increase the memory on each iteration based on the number of elements the user wants to add ? Currently it is stuck to the first entry of number of entered elements. E.g first time they want to add 4 nos and on second time they want to add 5 or 6 nos.

Comment: 1) You need to read in (`scanf`) the new number of elements, in another variable. Here, in the above code, we are just using previous `n`.       2) Donot use more `\n`, since `scanf` may read `\n` (ASCII:10).     3) Then use `realloc()` .      4) See this for proper usage of `realloc()` --> https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/g-fact-66/

Comment: Yeah was just a typing mistake in the second for loop; was using n instead of new variable. Problem solved 100%. \../